Solution of $\frac{rf'(r)+r^2f''(r)}{f(r)}=\lambda$
I am trying to find a solution for the following differential equation: $\frac{rf'(r)+r^2f''(r)}{f(r)}=\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is a constant.
My first ansatz was a polynomial of second order however I know that this can't be the intended answer because my professor gave us this excercise in an exam and we never solved a differential equation in this way. Moreover it would take us much time which I didn't have during the exam.
So my question is, are there any other ways of solving this differential equation in a more efficient way? I couldn't find an answer at first try.

A differential equation  of the form $x^2 , y'' + x , y - p^2 , y = 0$ is an Euler-Cauchy differential equation. In the case given a solution will of the form $y(r) = A , \cosh(p , \ln(r)) + B , \sinh(p , \ln(r))$ or of the form $y(r) = C , r^p + D , r^{-p}$.

Rearranging gives
$$r^2 f'' + r f' - \lambda f = 0 .$$
This Euler–Cauchy equation arises when solving Laplace's equation in polar coordinates, so I suspect it's a duplicate, but I couldn't find a suitable post to reference.
Hint Notice that if $f$ is a constant multiple of the power function $r^\mu$, then so is each term, which suggests using that quantity as an ansatz. Substituting in the differential equation yields the algebraic equation
$$(\mu^2 - \lambda) r^\mu = 0 .$$
From here, to express the general solution in real terms we need to split cases according to the sign of $\lambda$.
Alternatively (though it's less likely that this method is the intended one in a first course in differential equations), changing the independent variable via $r = \exp t$ transforms the equation to the well-known linear equation
$$f''(t) = \lambda f(t) .$$
Again continuing in real terms requires splitting cases according to the sign of $\lambda$.

In addition, to what Travis Willse has said, if $\lambda=0$, then:
\begin{align} rf''(r) + f'(r) = 0 \end{align}
which is a separable differential equation solved by:
\begin{align} f'(r) = A/r 
\Rightarrow f(r) = A \text{ln}(r) + C
\end{align}
where $A,C$ are some constants.
Also, another way to solve this differential equation is by changing variables from $r$ to $u := ln(r) \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dr} = 1/r$
This leads us to:
\begin{align} \frac{d^2f}{du^2}  = \lambda f \end{align}
This is a "standard" differential equation. (Exercise: fill in the details for how we got here.)
Letting $p := \sqrt{\lambda}$, we know that the solution for this equation is of the form:
\begin{align} f(u) = C_1 e^{pu} + C_2 e^{-pu} \end{align}
for some constants $C_1$ and $C_2$
Substitute $u = \text{ln } r$ and we should be done.
